# Parse and extract data from XML using Appcelerator

Tags: xml, appcelerator

Titanium SDK version: 1.6.1
iPhone SDK version: 4.2

I am having a hard time extracting the data from this XML output in Appcelerator. I would like to get the token and the username. How is this done?

```
<rsp stat="ok">
<auth>
<token>73257626300602415-3324a12587e2e9b3602</token>
<perms>delete</perms>
<user nsid="599323339@N047" username="theuser200" fullname="" />
</auth>
</rsp>
```

Thankful for all input.

Comment: You can check my answer on this site. http://stackoverflow.com/a/32690975/893872

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming your xml came from am xhr request then.

```
xhr.onload = function() {
  var doc = this.responseXML.documentElement; // Give me a xml document.
  var token = doc.getElementsByTagName("token").item(0).text; // Get the token element, then the first item (could be lots of them) then the text of the first.
  var username = doc.getElementsByTagName("user").item(0).getAttribute("username"); // Ditto as above, but this time get the attribute name "username"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you read [the API documentation](http://assets.appcelerator.com.s3.amazonaws.com/docs/API_TitaniumModule.pdf)?

`Titanium.XML` starts on page 506

Also, [this guide](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Working_with_XML_Data) may be of some help.

Comment: It's very standard DomDocument stuff.  Have you not worked with a DOM-based parser before?